Creating figure in Flutter with linked shapes
Well , lately i've been working on a FLUTTER project.
In this project im supposed to make a figure like the one below.
Does anyone have an idea how i could make it ?
Thank You.

I've tried CustomPainter but i could'nt reach a good solution.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

With No Provided Code:
There's nothing to offer rather than a vertical and horizontal dividers.
